# Modificar un registro de una estructura en un archivo en C

Tags: c, archivo

practicamente tengo que modificar el campo `.baja` de la estructura de `Cliente`  (esta si se modifica correctamente) y resulta que todos los otros campos tambien se modifican pero con contenido basura. La idea es que contengan lo mismo que tenian antes pero solo cambiando el `clienteBaja.baja`. Gracias

```
int buscaCliente(FILE*archi)
{
  Cliente clientes;
  int buscar=0;
  int  posicion=-1;
  if(archi!=NULL)
{
    printf("Ingrese el D.N.I. de un cliente a buscar\n");
    scanf("%i", &buscar);
    while(fread(&clientes,sizeof(Cliente),1,archi)>0)
    {
        if(buscar==clientes.dni)
        {
            posicion=ftell(archi)/sizeof(Cliente);
        }
    }
}
  return posicion;
}

void bajaCliente()                 
{
  Cliente clienteBaja;
  int posicion;
  FILE*archi=fopen("cliente","r+b");
  posicion=buscaCliente(archi);
  if(posicion==(-1))
{
    printf("El cliente no existe");
}
  else
{
    fseek(archi,(posicion-1)*(sizeof(Cliente)),SEEK_SET);
    clienteBaja.baja='s';
    fseek(archi,sizeof(Cliente),SEEK_CUR);
}    
  fwrite(&clienteBaja,sizeof(Cliente),1,archi);
  fclose(archi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que tu problema es que el cliente que estás modificando en baja es `clienteBaja`, el cual has creado dentro del método sin inicializar sus "atributos", por lo que éstos contienen valores "aleatorios". Por tanto, te recomendaría que leyeras con fread la posición entera del cliente al que le quieres modificar baja y guardaras su contenido en `clienteBaja`para tener los atributos originales antes de cambiar baja. Podrías hacer esto pasándole a `buscaCliente()` un puntero a `cliente` para así guardar el cliente encontrado en su contenido y posteriormente pasarle ese cliente a baja, es decir:

```
int buscaCliente(FILE*archi,Cliente* c )
{
  Cliente clientes;
  int buscar=0;
  int  posicion=-1;
  if(archi!=NULL)
{
    printf("Ingrese el D.N.I. de un cliente a buscar\n");
    scanf("%i", &buscar);
    while(fread(&clientes,sizeof(Cliente),1,archi)>0)
    {
        if(buscar==clientes.dni)
        {
            posicion=ftell(archi)/sizeof(Cliente);
            *c = clientes;
        }
    }
}
  return posicion;
}


void bajaCliente(Cliente c)                 
{
  Cliente clienteBaja = c;

  int posicion;
  FILE*archi=fopen("cliente","r+b");
  posicion=buscaCliente(archi);
  if(posicion==(-1))
{
    printf("El cliente no existe");
}
  else
{
    fseek(archi,(posicion-1)*(sizeof(Cliente)),SEEK_SET);
    clienteBaja.baja='s';
    fseek(archi,sizeof(Cliente),SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&clienteBaja,sizeof(Cliente),1,archi);
}    

  fclose(archi);
}
```

Además, yo metería el fwrite dentro del else, ya que si he entendido bien lo que pretendes hacer, no quieres escribir un nuevo cliente, sino modificar los datos de uno en caso de que exista